# Optimal lag length in VECM using vars R package

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I have some series that are cointegrated, so I know that I should fit a vector error correction model (VECM). Nevertheless I found no guidance in finding the optimal lag length, say `lagLength`.

I am using the "vars" package in R. In order to check cointegration I used `ca.jo(..,K=cointegrationLength)` and then used `cajoorls(...,K=lagLength)` to fit the VECM.

I do not understand:

1. the right interaction between `K` in both functions;
2. an "optimal" criterion to choose the lag lengths.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But how does it work then, if I want to cherry pick relevant lags? How can I do that in RStudio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For VEC models you should select number of lags based on information criteria on VAR model on levels of your time series. For that you can use function `VARselect` from the same package **vars**.

Function `cajorls` does not have the argument $K$. However it has the argument $r$, which denotes cointegration rank. Argument $K$ in function `ca.jo` controls the number of lags of VEC model.

The usual workflow for estimating VEC model is the following (rough outline). Suppose your time series is in the matrix `y`.

1. Find the number of lags using `VARselect(y)`
2. Determine the cointegration rank using the function `ca.jo`. Pass the number of lags found in the first step as argument `K`.
3. Fit VEC model using the cointegration vectors determined from the second step. This is performed by function `cajorls`, where you should pass the result of `ca.jo` and the number of cointegration vectors.

Comment: Thanks mpiktas, I suppose VaRselect to be run on stationary time series (e.g. differenced)....

Comment: @GiorgioSpedicato, no, `VARselect` is to be run on variables in levels (not differenced), assuming that your variables are integrated of first order and also cointegrated.